# Drupal 7, Creating Profile Type using list field. Trying to have 2nd list populated with values dependant on user selection on first list selection

Tags: drupal-7

How do you create a list field for a profile type where I can add a list of say cat, dog, spider etc. Then have the other list field populated with the breads of dog, cat, spiders, etc.

So when the user selects cat from the 1st list, the 2nd list gets populated with only the items for breads of cats.

Answer (score 1):

In D6 you could do this with hierarchical select on a standard cck field. I am assuming this form element would be available for a user profile in D7 as cck has been integrated into core fields. However, it looks like the D7 module is still in alpha but still may be worth trying. ref. http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select